# Is there a clustering algorithm that can take a maximum distance from any mean as a constraint?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, constraint

I am building an analytical tool that depends on being able to take a bunch of 1 dimensional numbers and group them into categories based on how close each number is to the mean of the group. However, instead of specifying the number of groups, I want to specify the maximum distance any individual member can be from the center of it's group.

My specific application is a list of times (from 00:00 to 23:59) and I want to partition the list into groups where no member is more than x minutes from the center of it's group. Other than this constraint, the objective function should be the same as the usual k means algorithm.

I am coding in R so if you know of a package I can use that would be terrific!
Off the top of my head, I can iteratively use the kmeans function and check the maximum distance and stop once it is below my threshold, but this is a pretty ugly solution. I am hoping there is a more direct way.

Comment: Your demands are not articulated enough. 1) What if the object is farther from centroid than the threshold - what is its destiny then? 2) Remember K-means is iterative. An object can be far from one iteration and get closer on another, or vice versa. What strategy then you want with that? 3) Is your task more than 1D (1 variable)? If not, there are other effective tools to "cluster" in addition to a cluster analysis.

Comment: Try to search also `constrained K-means`, maybe you find anything already answered.

Comment: @ttnphns, 1) Nothing should be farther than the threshold, it is a hard constraint. 2) I don't think I understand this point. 3) My task is 1D. I did try searching for constrained k-means, but the constraints are of a different sort (must/must not link constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that the case in 1D shouldn't be too hard, right?

In 1D, an optimal solution (in terms of number of clusters) might be easily found with starting at 0:00 (left). The most left point should be included in a cluster. Logically, the cluster center should be moved as far right as possible. Then iteratively, the same goes for the first point that is now not in the cluster. And so on, until you have all the points. So, no clustering exists that does better, in the sense that it works with fewer clusters.

This is without any penalty induced by being far away from a cluster center. If you want something better, you would at least have to induce a tradeoff, between the number of clusters and the distances until the center.

Perhaps if you want to do something with squares, this should be much like Gaussian Mixtures (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sBIC/vignettes/GaussianMixtures.pdf). But then, the constraint is not hard.

Comment: I'll give it a go and if it gives satisfactory results, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example LEADER clustering. But it's not very good.

Also, complete linkage HAC has this property.

Comment: Could you please explain further what you mean about complete link HAC? Of course you could make the clusters so that no two points are further apart than the maximum distance, but that would be overly restrictive. How would you control distance to the centroid?

Comment: It's overly restrictive, but it guarantees that the distance from the centroid is less than your threshold, too. You could also consider twice the distance. Or centroid linkage.

Comment: Centroid distance would exactly answer the question. Twice the distance with complete linkage could give incorrect answers.

Comment: I'm not convinced that centroid distance is more than a rough intuition of what happens there, because the "centroid" is never actually computed. I haven't seen a proof if/when that linkage guarantees such a centroid. Just like median linkage doesn't actually use a median anywhere. It roughly uses the midpoint of two previous clusters, but I don't see what definition of a median this would satisfy.

Comment: You are right.  None of these is 100% but still a useful answer.

Comment: That is why I suggested complete link, as it can guarantee a maximum distance. If you need this to be strict, complete-link is an option.